# boost::multiprecision : How to convert a mpz_int variable to gmp_int?

Tags: c++, boost, multiprecision

I have converted a `mpz_int` to `gmp_int` by converting a `mpz_int` to `mpz_class`
and then converting the `mpz_class` instance to a `gmp_int`.
Is there an easier way to do it ?
thanks

Answer (score 2):

From the [tutorial](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/multiprecision/doc/html/boost_multiprecision/tut/ints/gmp_int.html) and [documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/multiprecision/doc/html/boost_multiprecision/ref/number.html), there is a member function `backend()` in `mpz_int` that gives access to the underlying `gmp_int`.

Comment: From the documentation, there are a lot more methods. What's your point?

Comment: @sehe The question is "how do I convert from A to B" and the answer was "there is a function f in A", how can you not understand the point, seriously?

Comment: Well I missed the point "that gives access to the underlying `gmp_int`.", mainly because it was missing (zing) and I might have misread the question, as you already noticed.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the `convert_to<>` method seems to work: **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8c80221855f0c97a)**

```
#include <boost/multiprecision/mpfr.hpp>
#include <boost/multiprecision/cpp_int.hpp>

using namespace boost::multiprecision;

int main()
{
    cpp_int i;
    mpz_int z;

    i = z.convert_to<cpp_int>();
}
```

Comment: The question is about `gmp_int`, not `cpp_int` (I did not check if the trivial substitution works).